# Error en consulta Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Buenas noches,

creo que es una pregunta simple pero quizá por la hora que es no encuentro porque me falla Ajax en el login de usuarios:

Mi formulario:

```
<form id="form-validation" name="form-validation">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input id="validation-email"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
               name="login-username"
               type="text"
               data-validation="El usuario introducido no es válido">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input id="validation-password"
              class="form-control password"
              name="login-password"
              type="password" data-validation=""
              data-validation-message="Contraseña incorrecta"
              placeholder="Contraseña">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="remember" checked>
          Recordar
       </label>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-actions">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary width-150">Iniciar Sesión</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".form-actions > .btn").click(function(e){

    alert($("#form-validation").serialize());
    var base_url = $('#htmlbaseurl').text();

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: base_url + 'Pages/checklogin',
                data: $("#form-validation").serialize(),
                success:function(e){

                    alert("funciono");

                },
                error:function(e){

                alert("error");
                }
      });
  });

 });
```

Mi controlador Codeigniter

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    }

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $data['base_url'] = base_url();
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

    public function checklogin(){
        $email = $_POST['login-username'];
        $passwd = $_POST['login-password'];

        $query = $this->db->select('id')->from('users')->where('username', $email)->where('password', $passwd)->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            setcookie('c_pr_user2', $query->row()->userId, time()+(86400*30), '/');

            redirect(base_url().'');
        }
        else{
            echo 'Error credenciales';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ti fijaste en el inspector de elemento del navegador cual es el error que te da cuando se ejecuta el ajax

Comment: Me da un error 404 en 'Pages/checklogin'

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor de la variable `base_url`? Me parece que ese es el problema.

Comment: Es lo que dice @MarcosGallardo error 404 se da cuando no se encuentra esa dirección.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que error te aparece en la consola¿?

al parecer el error esta en tu url a la cual mandas la petición Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: base_url + 'Pages/checklogin', 
           data: $("#form-validation").serialize(),
           success:function(e){

              alert("funciono");

                },
                error:function(e){

                alert("error");
                }
      });
  });
```

en la variable que concatenas: base_url

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, el fallo está donde decís. La cuestión es que llevo apenas varios días trabajando con Codeigniter y no puedo hacerme una imagen clara de como funciona con este tipo de rutas. No se si es mucho pedir ¿Alguien me podría dar una buena explicación o facilitarme un manual donde pueda entender como trabajar con Codeigniter y contenido dinámico?